# How to make overflow blocks working well ()

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

Here is 8 floating blocks with equal content with some problems:

- if I use *padding:10px* for *sideblock .inner* to create "border" it does not work good (padding-bottom it's look like disapeared)
- if I put a cursor on block - it can't be appeared at the top, and do not move othes block

How makes block working well?
HTML:

```
<div class="sideblock"><div class="style-menu"><div class="inner">
Everything around you that you call life was made up by people that were no smarter than you, and you can change it, you can influence it, you can build your own things that other people can use.</div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.sideblock {
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;    
}

.sideblock .inner {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;}

.sideblock .style-menu {
    padding: 3px;
    background: #157ba1;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #157ba1 0%,#5fa31c 100%);}

.sideblock:hover {
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px #000;
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;}
```

Here is my code -  http://jsfiddle.net/2HqZV/1/

[image: How it would be]

Thx for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i assume you want the have the same look as when the div is hovered but then smaller?
 You shouldn't have to use any overflow on the div it self atfirst, it should response to your given height.

When you inspect your element you can easially see the heights of your elements.
You'll see that your `.style-menu` div hasn't the same height as `.sideblock`, to fix that you can add a inherit height to your style-menu:

```
.sideblock .style-menu {
     height: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
    background: #157ba1;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  #157ba1 0%,#5fa31c 100%);
}
```

Now when you look further you see that your padding at the `.inner` div element expends the actual given height. What you want is the padding to be inline. You can easially do this with [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). And finally you can 'cut' the text by adding a `overflow`:

```
.sideblock .inner {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    height: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HqZV/2/)**

I hope this is what you meant.

*btw, i find your way of adding a border very unique ^^*

---

**Update**

So to let every element that expends ignore every other element, you should take it out of the document flow. You can do this with `position: absolute;`. However what absolute position does is indeed ignoring all the other elements, but you want to have the same position. Because the element has no offset positioning (top, right, bottom, left) it will be placed at the left corner of your screen(acts like it is the only element in the DOM). 
 To keep the elements position we are not changing the `.sideblock` but the content of that; `.style-menu`:

```
.sideblock:hover .style-menu
{
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px #000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Because this element goes on top of the other, you want to add the shadow here.

Now the `.sideblock` element has no content because the content has become absolute and so out of the document flow. To fix this you can give this element a `min-height`:

```
.sideblock:hover 
{
    min-height: 80px;
    height: auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HqZV/5/)**

Comment: It looks better. Thank you. But i have to show content on top of the blocks.

I've added image to th question to describe that.

Comment: Yahoo! Its simple working :) I'm starting to implementing your solution right now. Thank you a very much!